# Proper Way to Refresh Android ListVew while in another Tab

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Basically I have two tabs.  A Fragment and a ListFragment.

When in the Fragment, you can insert data into a Database that will populate a ListView in the ListFragment Tab directly next to it.  I want to be able to swipe to that ListFragment (after inserting new data) and while using the ViewPager function for swiping, I want the ListView to refresh.

Is there a proper way to do this?  I can show code if requested; but not sure which code to show.  To start, here is my View pager setup:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

}
```

Please note:  This is NOT a dual pane setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do it is to have your `ListFragment` implement the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>` interface and initialize a `Loader` to load the data being bound to the `ListView`.

You can read this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) to learn more about `Loader`s.

Comment: Well, I am marking you correct and +1'ing the answer since that answered the question.  If you can show me a very basic skeleton coding structure I would appreciate that!

Comment: I recently [**blogged**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) about `Loader`'s... it gives an example of how to implement the `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` with a `ListFragment`. Hopefully you will find it informative.

Comment: There is also a ton of sample code on `Loader`s in the API Demos sample code in the Android SDK.